# Ubuntu 16.04 slow boot kernel for Thinkstation P910 with correct /etc/fstab

Tags: boot

My Thinkstation P910 with Ubuntu 16.04 is taking a really long time to boot.

systemd-analzye gave this output:

```
Startup finished in 27.997s (firmware) + 5.328s (loader) + 1min 36.900s (kernel) + 12.821s (userspace) = 2min 23.048s
```

My /etc/fstab matches the output of blkid. All of the UUIDs are correct.

Any idea why the kernel would take so long and how I can fix it?

Edit:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame

9.115s NetworkManager-wait-online.service

6.880s plymouth-quit-wait.service

2.444s apt-daily-upgrade.service




$ systemd-analyze critical-chain 

graphical.target @16.929s

└─multi-user.target @16.929s

  └─getty.target @16.929s

    └─getty@tty1.service @16.929s

      └─rc-local.service @10.041s +2ms

        └─network-online.target @10.039s

          └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @923ms +9.115s

            └─NetworkManager.service @875ms +46ms

              └─dbus.service @785ms

                └─basic.target @776ms

                  └─sockets.target @776ms

                    └─snapd.socket @772ms +1ms

                      └─sysinit.target @771ms

                        └─apparmor.service @707ms +62ms

                          └─local-fs.target @706ms

                            └─run-user-124.mount @10.212s

                              └─local-fs-pre.target @154ms

                                └─systemd-remount-fs.service @149ms +3ms

                                  └─systemd-journald.socket @103ms
```

Comment: Read `man systemd-analyze`, and use some of the other options, like `systemd-analyze blame`, and `systemd-analyze critical-chain ...` for some units.

Comment: You can remove the quiet and splash option in grub menu (press e key to edit temporary the boot option), you will see more information for kernel message during boot. You can even add debug instead the quiet option in order to have a lot of details.

Comment: I ran systemd-analyze blame and it only showed the userspace times, none of which take an unreasonable time. It did not show infomration for the kernel boot.
I ran systemd-analyze critical-chain. Please see the critical chain in the edit.